# Google Calendar Privacy Issues

Tags: privacy, google-calendar

#### Does Google have access to the data stored in my Google Calendar?

As Google Calendar seems to be the best option for Android users and is widely used, I was wondering if Google actually uses your personal data of events and tasks for their personalized ads. Looking at how Google threads privacy with their Gmail service (e.g. a [Report](https://www.wsj.com/articles/techs-dirty-secret-the-app-developers-sifting-through-your-gmail-1530544442) from the WSJ), it would be interesting to know if the same pracitces are applied with their Calendar application.

Comment: Have you seen the Google's Privacy Policy page, specifically the [What Google Collects](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en#infocollect) and [Why Google Collects](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en#whycollect) sections.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is stored in server of someone else they do have access to data you have stored, but it's different thing do they allow their employees access to data. I'd say no. They won't never give their employees access to your data, but if you read their terms of service you will find it out how they use your data. If they "access to your data" I believe they do not access to data themselves. It's like a bot which finds your interests and fetches more interesting ads front of your face, but basically none of the real persons do not know your interests. Data is anonymous. They use something else than your name or email to identify you to show you ads of your interests.

Comment: I would like to see some actual sources not just assumptions. And regarding your statement that only algortihms are going to read your data, that wasn't the case with Gmail. Humans also had access and used it to read private mails.

Comment: https://safety.google/privacy/data/